# How to run dynamic code in Rails models in a production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model, production

I'd like to add a `get_options` method to my model. However, it is my understanding that in a production environment, models only get run once. I need to use I18n in my model, and so the output will change based on the language the user chose.
How do I make something like this work in production?

```
class ListHourlyPay < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.get_options
    ListHourlyPay.all.map(&:amount).index_by { |obj| I18n.t("activerecord.attributes.part_time.hourly_pay_options.#{obj}") }
  end
end
```

Thanks!

p.s. I'm not even sure this *doesn't* work - it is just my suspicion based on what I've heard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, models are run once, but methods are called multiple times. Any time `get_options` is called, the string will be re-translated - I wouldn't worry.

Comment: I'll take your word for it :) Thanks!